# Finding Index # from Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to loop through an array of elements and find the index # of the one that matches certain criteria. Take the following array:

```
services: [
  { _id: <ObjectId>,
    name: "initiating"
  },
  { _id: <ObjectId>,
    name: "evaluating"
  },
  { _id: <ObjectId>,
    name: "servicing"
  },
]
```

How would I loop through this array and pull out the array index # of the object where the property "name" is equal to "evaluating" (i.e. - array element #1)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`Array.prototype.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```js
const services = [
  { _id: 1,
    name: "initiating"
  },
  { _id: 2,
    name: "evaluating"
  },
  { _id: 3,
    name: "servicing"
  },
];

console.log(
    services.findIndex(({ name }) => name === 'evaluating')
);
```

Comment: Perfect! Much appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome! Note though that IE (of course) does not support it. Check the link for a polyfill :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let services = [{
    _id: 0,
    name: "initiating"
  },
  {
    _id: 1,
    name: "evaluating"
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    name: "servicing"
  },
]

let selected = services.findIndex(service => service.name == "evaluating")
console.log(selected)
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I don't need the element returned, I need the index #.

Comment: @Muirik Sorry, my bad. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let services = [{
    _id: 0,
    name: "initiating"
  },
  {
    _id: 1,
    name: "evaluating"
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    name: "servicing"
  },
];

let index = services.findIndex(item => item.name === "evaluating");
document.write(index);
```

This will return the index after searching through the each object's name property and comparing it to "evaluating".

Answer (score 0):

You may use [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var services = [
    {
        _id: '<ObjectId>',
        name: "initiating"
    },
    {
        _id: '<ObjectId>',
        name: "evaluating"
    },
    {
        _id: '<ObjectId>',
        name: "servicing"
    },
];
var idx = services.reduce((x, ele, idx) => (ele.name=='evaluating') ? idx : x, -1);

console.log(idx);
```